# How to add and if condition into an append() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, if-statement, append

I am finishing up a TwitchTV project but have been struggling to figure out how to append some code with jQuery. This code needs to check the API to see if a user is streaming or not, then, depending on if he or she is or not, append information to an already dynamic, jQuery produced html.

Take a look at my JavaScript code. Right now, under the “status” row, you will see each user has info. If the user is offline, I would simply like to have the html read “offline.” If the user is online, I would like it to read "Online: " plus a short description of what the channel is about (the stream information is stored in a variable called “stream,” and the short description is stored in a variable called “statusWhat”).

I’m sorry if that is a bit confusing. I think seeing the code will make things clear: https://codepen.io/JayDevelopment/pen/bMKrLK 1

```
$(function() {
  var twitchers = [
    "ESL_SC2",
    "OgamingSC2",
    "cretetion",
    "storbeck",
    "habathcx",
    "RobotCaleb",
    "noobs2ninjas"
  ];

  //FREECODECAMP STREAM INFO AND API CALL
  var url =
    "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?client_id=jjqkn1xu4g4rx7d3e1o5refrmw5bhd";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    if (data.stream === null) {
      $("#fccStatus").html("OFFLINE");
    } else {
      $("#fccStatus").html("FreeCodeCamp is ONLINE");
    }
    $('#fccGame').html()
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < twitchers.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" +
        twitchers[i] +
        "?client_id=jjqkn1xu4g4rx7d3e1o5refrmw5bhd",
      success: function(dataFor) {
        $.getJSON(
          "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" +
          dataFor.name +
          "?client_id=jjqkn1xu4g4rx7d3e1o5refrmw5bhd").done(function(data2) {
            var name = dataFor.name;
            var logo = dataFor.logo;
            var statusWhat = dataFor.status;
            var stream = data2.stream;

            $('#info').append('<div class="row block">' +
              '<div class="col-sm">' +
              '<h1>' + '<img src=' + logo + '>' + '</h1>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="col-sm">' +
              '<h1>' + name + '</h1>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="col-sm" id="change">' +
              '<a href="https://www.twitch.tv/' + name + '"' + ' target="blank">' +
              '<h1 id="status">' + stream + ': ' + statusWhat + '</h1>' +
              '</a></div></div></div>')

            /* if (stream === null) {
              $("#status").append('OFFLINE');
            } else {
              $("#status").append('ONLINE: ' + statusWhat);
            }  */
          }
        );
      },
      error: function(error) {
        $("#logo").append('<img src=' + '#' + '>' + "<br>");
        $("#name").append('Invalid' + "<br>");
        $('#status').append('Not found');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that you're **appending** IDs inside your loop (`<h1 id="status">`). This results in duplicate IDs on the page, which is invalid markup. jQuery doesn't know what to do in this situation, so will only work for the first ID. To resolve this, use classes instead :)

Comment: Is that your desired output? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGaYxK . As you said it is pretty confusing, like stream when it is not null, is an object, I assumed you wanted the game title, wich is in stream.game. Then as mentioned by @ObsidianAge there was the id problem. Also, Using append in if(stream === null) would have resulted in null:null OFFLINE

Comment: Lol, good point. Thanks, Barmar!

Comment: @Lou, my working knowledge of javascript/jQuery is basic. If you have any suggestions for improvements, they are welcome. My main goal is just to have the status read 'offline' if offline, and if online then online: ['game/user status here'] I am not sure my current approach is the best one.

Comment: @JordansMerrill can you check out that codepen link ive joined in my previous comment and tell me if it suits your needs. If so i'll write what have been done as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks! The method I tried using after getting Barmar's help kept leaving me with an "object object" text before "online" and I could not figure out why.  Your code definitely does what I was trying to do. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it when you assign to the `stream` variable:

```
if (data2.stream) {
    stream = data2.stream + " ONLINE: " + statusWhat;
} else {
    stream = "OFFLINE";
}
```